# df.loc() doesn't seem to be working or filtering out the rows I need

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to use `df.loc` to calculate the number of orders per courier that are eligible for a bonus pay.

```
df['Eligible'] = df.loc[(df['DeliveryOnTime'] == "On-time") & (df['DeliveryOnTime'] == "Early"), 'Total Orders'].sum()
```

So what I want to do is to create a new column called `Eligible` using data from `DeliveryOnTime` with rows that have `On-time` and `Early` to perform a total count.

This information will be used to calculate the bonus pay:

```
df['Success Rate'] = df['Eligible']/df['Total Orders']

df['Bonus'] = df['Eligible'].mul(1.2).where(df['Success Rate'] >= 0.95)
```

It seems that the `Eligible` code isn't working as the number of `Total Orders` and `Eligible` are exactly the same for every ID when there should be differences as some deliveries will be marked as `Late` in `DeliveryOnTime`

**Sample Data**

```
df = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
         'DeliveryOnTime': ["On-time", "Late", "Early", "On-time", "On-time", "Late", "Early", "Early"],
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#For the sake of example data, the count of `DeliveryOnTime` will be the total number of orders. 
df['Total Orders'] = df['DeliveryOnTime'].count()
```

So in this example:
ID 1's success rate would be 66.66 with 2 out of 3 orders being eligible for bonus pay.

Only ID's 2 and 5 would qualify as their success rate would be over 95.

Comment: please add a reproducible example

Comment: Please add good example data, and an expected result.

Comment: Since you already have code: what is not working?

Comment: @9769953 I need the code to apply to every row with instances where they're `On-time` and `Early`. Added a small sample data, hopefully that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Will this helps?

```
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
         'DeliveryOnTime': ["On-time", "Late", "Early", "On-time", "On-time", "Late", "Late", "Early", "Early"],
      }
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data['Eligible']=data['DeliveryOnTime'].apply(lambda x: x in ['On-time', 'Early'])
g = data.groupby(['ID'])
success_rate_by_ID = g['Eligible'].apply(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x))
print(success_rate_by_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the dataframe transform to create an eligible column value then sum the column.  Group by courier id and filter where eligible equals 1 and count the index